# What is the connection between $\rho$ and $\sigma$ if $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I want to prove that there exists a Borel function $R(\rho,\sigma)$ with values in $M^{d\times d}$ defined on $D=\lbrace(\rho,\sigma)\in M^{d\times d}\times M^{d\times d}\,: \rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T\rbrace$ such that $\sigma=\rho R(\rho,\sigma)$ and $RR^T=I$.

My idea is: Diagonalize $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T=QDQ^T$ where Q is an orthogonal matrix.

It's obvious that $\sigma=UQ\sqrt{D}$ with U orthogonal matrix satisfies the request but is this the only possibility? I would appreciate any possible help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the 'e' mean in the expression $\sigma = \rho R(\rho,\sigma) \text{ e } RR^T = I$? It looks like a typo.

Comment: I think you're looking for a function $R(\rho,\sigma)$ such that $\sigma = \rho R(\rho,\sigma)$, right? Obviously, $R(\rho,\sigma)$ is uniquely determined for invertible $\rho$. You may then be able to extend $R$ to non-invertible $\rho$ by some type of limit construction, e.g., $R(\sigma,\rho) = \lim_{\lambda \to 0^+} \sigma (\rho + \lambda I)^{-1}$. I haven't checked whether this works, e.g., whether this limit even exists.

Comment: @WillNelson: I'm sorry, it's an error, I wanted to write and instead of e. I'm correcting it.

Comment: @WillNelson  : But I want $R(\rho,\sigma)$ to be an orthogonal matrix, thus there are problems even in the case of an invertible $\rho$.

Comment: @WillNelson : In fact, if $\rho$ is invertible then $R=\sigma\rho^{-1}$ is orthogonal. Thus we have only to prove it in the case of $\rho$ non invertible.

Comment: @WillNelson : Ok, but what can I do in the general case? The limit construction you mentioned before doesn't seem clear.

Comment: @WillNelson I believe you’re mistaken, it does necessarily follow. First, if $\sigma=\rho R$ then $R$ is $\rho^{-1}\sigma$ not $\sigma\rho^{-1}$ as you wrote. Also, $\alpha=\rho^{-1}$ is orthogonal if $\rho$ is, so that if we put $R=\alpha\sigma$, we have $R^{T}=\sigma^{T}\alpha^{T}$ so that
$RR^{T}=\alpha\sigma\sigma^{T}\alpha^{T}=\alpha\rho\rho^{T}\alpha^{T}=I$ since $\alpha=\rho^{-1}$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Alright. Clearly, I made a mistake in the expression for $R$. That fed through to suggesting the condition for $R$ being orthogonal is $\rho^T \rho=\sigma^T \sigma$. Using the correct expression $R=\rho^{-1}\sigma$ gives the condition on $R$ being orthogonal $\rho \rho^T = \sigma\sigma^T$, as required in the problem statement. Thus, for invertible $\rho$ (equivalently $\sigma$), the problem seems trivial: $R=\rho^{-1}\sigma$ is the unique matrix meeting the requirements. For singular $\rho (\sigma)$, perhaps a limit construction can be used as I mentioned in my second comment.

Comment: Suppose $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$. Diagonalize: $\rho\rho^T=UDU^T$. Then $\rho=U\sqrt{D}V$ and $\sigma=U\sqrt{D}V'$ for some orthogonal $V,V'$. And then $R=V^TV'$. This at least shows there's always an $R$ satisfying the given requirements for all $\rho$,$\sigma$. But can we find a *measurable* $R$? I think the answer is obviously yes. In fact, I suspect a continuous $R$ can be found. But no proof at the moment.

Comment: @WillNelson : I have thought of this and it seems correct but how can I prove that $\rho\rho^T=UDU^T\implies\rho=U\sqrt{D}V$?

Comment: If $\rho\rho^T=UDU^T$, then $(U^T\rho)(U^T\rho)^T = D$. It follows that $U^T\rho = \sqrt{D} V$ for some orthogonal $V$. (See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Unitary_freedom_of_square_roots) Wikipedia entry.) Then $\rho=U\sqrt{D}V$.

Comment: There can't be a continuous $R(\rho,\sigma)$ satisfying the given conditions. For any orthogonal $U$, choose an invertible $\rho$ arbitrarily close to $0$. Then $R(\rho,\rho U) = U$. This shows $R$ can't be continuous at $\rho=\sigma=0$. But *measurable* $R$... maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I rewrote this post. I left the original post bellow, because there are comments related to this original post.

Let $\Im(A)$ denote the image of $A$ and $M_k$ the set of real matrices of order $k$.

**Proposition:** Let $\rho,\sigma\in M_k$. 
These matrices satisfy $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$
if and only if $\rho R(\rho,\sigma)=\sigma$, such that $R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T$ is an orthogonal projection onto the $\Im(\rho^T)$. Moreover, $R(\rho,\sigma)$ can be chosen to be a borel function of $\rho$ and $\sigma$.

**Remark:** Notice that if $\rho$ is invertible then $\Im(\rho^T)=\mathbb{R}^k$ and the only orthogonal projection onto $\Im(\rho^T)=\mathbb{R}^k$ is $Id$. Thus, $R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T=Id$.

**Proof:** Suppose $\rho R(\rho,\sigma)=\sigma$. Then $\rho R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$.

Now, since $R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T$ is an orthogonal projection onto the $\Im(\rho^T)$ then $R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T\rho^T=\rho^T$. Thus,  $\rho R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T\rho^T=\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T.$

Next, suppose $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$. Then, $\Im(\rho)=\Im(\sigma)$.

Let $\rho^+$ be the pseudo inverse of $\rho$. Thus, $\rho\rho^+$ is an orthogonal projection onto the $\Im(\rho)=\Im(\sigma)$.
Thus, $\rho\rho^+\sigma=\sigma$. Define $R(\rho,\sigma)=\rho^{+}\sigma$.

Notice that $R(\rho,\sigma)R(\rho,\sigma)^T=\rho^{+}\sigma\sigma^T(\rho^{+})^T=\rho^{+}\rho\rho^T(\rho^{+})^T=\rho^{+}\rho(\rho^{+}\rho)^T=(\rho^{+}\rho)^2=\rho^{+}\rho$.
Remind that $\rho^{+}\rho$ is an orthogonal projection onto $\Im(\rho^T)$.

Finally, $R(\rho,\sigma)=\rho^{+}\sigma$ is borel because $f(\rho)=\rho^+$ is borel, since it is a pointwise limit of borel functions:

$f(\rho)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0+} f_h(\rho)$, where $f_h(\rho)=(\rho^T\rho+hId)^{-1}\rho^T$.

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse )

$\square$

---

Original Post:

For the real case, it is possible to obtain a borel function $R(\rho,\sigma)$ such that 
$\rho R(\rho,\sigma)=\sigma$.

Let $\rho,\sigma$ be real matrices of order k. Let $\Im(A)$ denote the image of $A$.

If $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$ then $\Im(\rho)=\Im(\sigma)$.

Let $\rho^+$ be the pseudo inverse of $\rho$. Thus, $\rho\rho^+$ is an orthogonal projection onto the $\Im(\rho)=\Im(\sigma)$.
Thus, $\rho\rho^+\sigma=\sigma$.

Let us define $R(\rho,\sigma)=\rho^{+}\sigma$. Notice that
the function $R(\rho,\sigma)$ is borel because $f(\rho)=\rho^+$ is borel, since it is a pointwise limit of borel functions:

$f(\rho)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0+} f_h(\rho)$, where $f_h(\rho)=(\rho^T\rho+hId)^{-1}\rho^T$.

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse )

Comment: $\rho^+\sigma$ isn't orthogonal (the problem requires $RR^T=I$) for non-invertible $\rho$. But maybe there's a way to make the pseudo-inverse work...

Comment: @WillNelson Indeed it does not need to be orthogonal, actually it does not need to be invertible. But the real matrices $\rho$ and $\sigma$ such that $\rho\rho^T=\sigma\sigma^T$ satisfy $\rho R=\sigma$, where $RR^T$ is an orthogonal projection $(RR^T=\rho^+\sigma\sigma^T(\rho^+)^T=\rho^+\rho\rho^T(\rho^+)^T=(\rho^+\rho)^2=\rho^+\rho)$. We can describe the connection without $RR^T=Id$, but still with $R(\rho,\sigma)$ borel.